# Convert 4229,4 to 4229.4000000 in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, decimal, varchar

I am very much new to sql.
Can anyone help me in turning the data 4229,4 to 4229.4000000 ?

Current data    : `4229,4`
expected output : `4229.4000000`

Comment: Please explain ore about your scenario. How do you get this data? From a table? Are converting a string to a number or a number to a string?

Comment: I am receiving this from a table

Comment: You've answered one of my questions.

Comment: Is 4229,4 stores in a table as a numeric type or a varchar type?

Comment: What is your locale set to?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have a table called T42 with a column called NUMBER_STR which has strings of numbers in the format `nnnn,nnn`. This function call will replace the comma with a decimal point and cast the string to a number, to seven places:

```
select number_str
       ,cast(replace(number_str, ',', '.') as number(38,7)) as number_nbr
from t42
/
```

Here is [a demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=180ebae7ea92bfa3b1e229bb748b5a0a). Bear in mind that rendering numbers is the responsibility of the client. Most UIs will hide trailing zeroes by default.

Note that the above solution assumes the string column contains only valid numbers. The lessons of history are that this is a dangerous assumption: eventually any loosely-typed column will contain strings which deviate from the expected format. Oracle 12c R2 introduced a helpful function `validate_conversion()` which allows us to check whether a value can be converted to a different datatype. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD).

Answer (score 0):

```
select
     rpad(replace(substr('4229,4',1,instr('4229,4',',',1) ),',','.')
          || substr('4229,4',instr('4229,4',',',1) + 1,length('4229,4') ),12,0)
 from
     dual
```

This will work for all, irrespective of where position of comma and length of text that you will pass. It will output a fixed length(12) string always.

Although, `rpad` returns string value. So you might have to take this into account if reusing the value.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I am actually looking for something dynamic. the data is actually looks like 3234,3 or 125,5 ( comma ',' and not decimal '.' )  and i need to convert it into 4229.4000000 every time in this format. Thank you for your response

Comment: @Pratik I have edited the answer. Kindly revert if any issues. For dynamic part, in place of '4229,4'(without single quote) place your column name from where you are fetching data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to format your number_str:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(<NUMBER_STR>||'0000000', '(\d+),(\d{7})\d*','\1.\2') FROM <TABLE>
```